# Server failed to start in eclipse juno

Tags: java, eclipse, jsp, servlets

I wrote a servlet and when i tried to run the code it came up with the following message:
"Server Tomcat7.0 at server localhost failed to start."I have tried every possible trick known to me but it does not work.I have cleaned the server as stated in other similar links given before here.I have successfully execute JSP files before.The code i am running as the servlet file is:

```
import java.io.PrintWriter;

import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

import business.User;
import data.UserIO;

@WebServlet("/AddToEmailListServlet")
public class AddToEmailListServlet extends HttpServlet 
{
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException 
{
    doPost(request,response);
}

/**
 * @see HttpServlet#doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
 */
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException 
{
    String firstname=request.getParameter("firstname");
    String lastname=request.getParameter("lastname");
    String emailaddress=request.getParameter("emailaddress");
    String getmail=request.getParameter("addEmail");
    String country=request.getParameter("country");

    ServletContext sc=this.getServletContext();
    String path=sc.getRealPath("/WEB-INF/EmailList.txt");

    User user=new User(lastname,firstname,emailaddress);
    UserIO.add(user, path);

    response.setContentType("text/html;charset-UTF-8");
    PrintWriter out=response.getWriter();
    out.println("<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC \"-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN\" \"http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd\">\n"
    +"<html>\n"
    +"<head>\n"
    +"<title>Insert title here</title>\n"
    +"</head>\n"
    +"<body>\n"
    +"<h1>Thanks for joining our email list.</h1>\n"
    +"<p>Here is the information you entered.</p>\n"
    +"<table cellspacing=\"5\" cellpadding=\"5\" border=\"1\">\n"
    +"<tr>\n"
    +"<td align=\"right\">First name:</td>\n"
    +"<td>"+firstname+"</td>\n"
    +"</tr>\n"
    +"<tr>\n"
    +"<td align=\"right\">Last name:</td>\n"
    +"<td>"+lastname+"</td>\n"
    +"</tr>\n"
    +"<tr>\n"
    +"<td align=\"right\">Email address:</td>\n"
    +"<td>"+emailaddress+"</td>\n"
    +"</tr>\n"
    +"</table>\n"
    +"<p>Toenter another email address click on the Back <br>\n"
    +"button browser or the Return button shown <br> below</p>\n"
    +"Your country is"+country+"<br>\n"
    +"<form action=\"JoinEmailList.html\" method=\"post\">\n"
    +   "<input type=\"submit\" value=\"Return\">\n"
    +"</form>\n"
    +"</body>\n"
    +"</html>\n");
    out.close();
}
}
```

The neccessary web.xml file is as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app version="2.5" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee
http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd">
<!-- the definition of the servlet -->
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>AddToEmailListServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>AddToEmailListServlet</servlet-class>
</servlet>
<!-- the mapping for the servlets -->
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>AddToEmailListServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/addToEmailList</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
<!-- other settings -->
<session-config>
    <session-timeout>30</session-timeout>
</session-config>
<welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>JoinEmailList2.html</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>
</web-app>
```

What else do i need to do to?

The stacktrace on the console is:

```
Aug 28, 2014 11:26:43 AM org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener init
INFO: The APR based Apache Tomcat Native library which allows optimal performance in production environments was not found on the java.library.path: /usr/java/packages/lib/amd64:/usr/lib64:/lib64:/lib:/usr/lib
Aug 28, 2014 11:26:43 AM org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.SetPropertiesRule begin
WARNING: [SetPropertiesRule]{Server/Service/Engine/Host/Context} Setting property 'source' to 'org.eclipse.jst.jee.server:Test' did not find a matching property.
Aug 28, 2014 11:26:44 AM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-8080"]
Aug 28, 2014 11:26:44 AM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["ajp-bio-8009"]
Aug 28, 2014 11:26:44 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina load
INFO: Initialization processed in 798 ms
Aug 28, 2014 11:26:44 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService startInternal
INFO: Starting service Catalina
Aug 28, 2014 11:26:44 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine startInternal
INFO: Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/7.0.55
Aug 28, 2014 11:26:44 AM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-8080"]
Aug 28, 2014 11:26:44 AM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["ajp-bio-8009"]
Aug 28, 2014 11:26:44 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start
INFO: Server startup in 649 ms
Aug 28, 2014 11:28:03 AM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: Marking servlet AddToEmailListServlet as unavailable
Aug 28, 2014 11:28:03 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve invoke
SEVERE: Allocate exception for servlet AddToEmailListServlet
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: email.AddToEmailListServlet
at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1720)
at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1571)
at org.apache.catalina.core.DefaultInstanceManager.loadClass(DefaultInstanceManager.java:530)
at org.apache.catalina.core.DefaultInstanceManager.loadClassMaybePrivileged(DefaultInstanceManager.java:512)
at org.apache.catalina.core.DefaultInstanceManager.newInstance(DefaultInstanceManager.java:139)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.loadServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1148)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.allocate(StandardWrapper.java:864)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:134)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:122)
at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:501)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:103)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:950)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:116)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1070)
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:611)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:314)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Comment: Are you getting the error on the console, with a stacktrace, or in the dialog window? In the former case, please post the whole console log, in the second, there should be a "more info" button on that dialog, please post what it shows.

Answer (score 2):

The name in  tag is not same. They should be same, like

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>AddToEmailListServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>email.AddToEmailListServlet</servlet-class>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>AddToEmailListServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/addToEmailList</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

Comment: But now it just leads to HTTP Status Error 500.

Comment: Do you have a class AddToEmailListServlet under package email?

Comment: No there is no such package

Comment: Then you need to change that in the servlet-class.
Put like package.ClassName in <servlet-class>